# Is there an article in: "down memory lane"?

Tags: articles, idioms

I am racking my brains on the correct usage of the phrase.
Is  "down memory lane" or "down **the** memory lane" the right one to use?

All my searching points to the former, but I am unable to come to grips with it because of the usage in a nursery rhyme "[Baa, baa, black sheep](http://www.wolverton-mountain.com/articles/baa-baa-black-sheep.html)" where one of the lines is "... little boy who lives down **the** lane".

Can you please clarify?

Comment: "Memory Lane" would be its name, even though it is not always written as such; therefore no article.

Comment: The established usage is [***racking** your brain(s)*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=racked+my+brain%2Cwracked+my+brain%2Craked+my+brain%2Cracked+my+brains%2Cwracked+my+brains%2Craked+my+brains&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cracked%20my%20brain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwracked%20my%20brain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craked%20my%20brain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cracked%20my%20brains%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwracked%20my%20brains%3B%2Cc0) (usually pluralised). ***Wracking*** is a more recent (eggcorn?) form, but ***raking*** doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

Memory lane is figuratively a name of a lane that you can take a walk in. Compare: Wall Street, Sunset Boulevard, Park Avenue.

It is not capitalized because it not a real name, the word "memory" refers to real memory.
See this [dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+stroll+down+memory+lane) too.